# Unix terminal: split file into 4 equal parts

Tags: file, unix, split, terminal

I am working on a remote unix server and I need to split a 300gb file into 4 equal parts in the terminal.

I tried to run this command:

```
$ split -n 4 -d bigfile.txt
```

but I get the following output:

```
split: invalid option -- 'n'
```

I can't install any other package on the server so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't mention what brand and version of Unix that you're using. You're not using GNU `split`, though, so I'm guessing it's not Linux. Run `man split` and see what options it has. This really belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) though as it doesn't have much to do with programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-l` with `split` command, which specifies how many lines you want in each smaller file(`default is 1000 lines`).

So, one approach could be, you could find total lines in the big file:

```
tot_lines=`wc -l bigfile.txt`
```

Then you can split it into 4 parts by assigning lines=`echo $((tot_lines / 4))` to each file.

`split -l $lines bigfile.txt`